# Modular Template Resolver In Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am reading the [Thymeleaf + Spring 3 Tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleafspring3.html) and also trying to build a modular application. My goal is to be able to load thymeleaf templates from Jars in the classpath.

For this I have configured a `SpringTemplateEngine` in the next xml:

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <util:set>
            <ref bean="servletContextTemplateResolver" />
            <ref bean="classpathPluginTemplateResolver" />
        </util:set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="classpathPluginTemplateResolver"
    class="org.mael.codex.arcana.web.thymeleaf.templates.ClasspathPluginTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/META-INF/codexarcana/plugin/views" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
```

And the ClasspathPluginTemplateResolver code:

```
public class ClasspathPluginTemplateResolver extends TemplateResolver {

public ClasspathPluginTemplateResolver() {
    super();
    super.setResourceResolver(new ClasspathTemplateResolver());
}

@Override
public void setResourceResolver(IResourceResolver resourceResolver) {
    throw new ConfigurationException("Cannot set a resource resolver on "
            + this.getClass().getName() + ". If "
            + "you want to set your own resource resolver, use "
            + TemplateResolver.class.getName() + "instead");
}
}
```

And the ClasspathTemplateResolver:

```
public class ClasspathTemplateResolver implements IResourceResolver {

@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}

@Override
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(
        TemplateProcessingParameters templateProcessingParameters,
        String resourceName) {

    if (resourceName == null || resourceName.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource name cannot be null");
    }

    try {
        return new ClassPathResource(resourceName).getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open resource '" + resourceName
                + "'", e);
    }
}
```

}

How can I avoid name conflicts in the templates resolved by the ClasspathPluginTemplateResolver?

Example:

Let's suppose I have 2 plugins with this directory structure:

```
codexarcana-poll-plugin.jar
    ----/META-INF/codexarcana/plugin/views/wizard.html
```

and

```
codexarcana-gravatar-plugin.jar
    ----/META-INF/codexarcana/plugin/views/wizard.html
```

In this case I believe that the ClasspathTemplateResolver will return a wrong view or will have conflicts resolving such thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implementations of the `ITemplateResolver` interface that extend the base `org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver` class (like all out-of-the-box implementations do) have a `resolvablePatterns` property that allows you to specify a series of patterns that will be applied for determining which views will be considered *resolvable* by that specific template engine. This should help you avoid collisions.

There you can specify wildcarded patterns like `admin/*`, `user/*/create`, etc.

Have in mind that these patterns apply on the **view name**, and not on the template file name itself. For example, if your template is `/WEB-INF/templates/index.html` and your view resolver adds prefix `/WEB-INF/templates/` and suffix `.html`, your *view name* is `index`, and so a *resolvable pattern* like `*.html` would never match.

Also, there is an `order` property that establishes the order in which template resolvers will be asked to resolve a view.

Disclaimer, as required by StackOverflow rules: I'm the author of Thymeleaf.

Comment: An answer from the source? Thats great! Gracias!